# Prove that $x \leq c(t) \implies \inf\{s \in [0,b): c(s) > x \} \leq t$ where $c$ is right-continuous and increasing

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

My question comes from Exercise 5.14 (p.33) of *Probability and Stochastics* by Cinlar. I think I almost have the solution, but there is a particular step that I've been stuck on for several hours. Here's the question:

> **5.14** *(Distribution functions and measures on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$)* Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ (with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra) such that $c(t) = \mu[0,t]$ is finite for every $t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$. The limit $b = c(\infty) = \lim_{t \to \infty} c(t)$ is allowed to be $+\infty$.
>
> (a) Show that $c$ is increasing and right-continuous. It is called the cumulative distribution function associated with $\mu$.
>
> (b) Define $a(u)$ as in Exercise 5.13 for $u \in [0,b)$, and let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $[0,b)$. Show that
> $$ \mu = \lambda \circ a^{-1}. $$
> This demonstrates Theorem 5.4 in the case of measures like the present $\mu$. Incidentally, we have also shown that to every increasing right-continuous function $c$ from $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ there corresponds a unique measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ whose cumulative distribution function is $c$.

Part (a) was easy. For part (b), the function $a: \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}_{+}$ is defined as
$$ a(u) := \inf\{t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}: c(t) > u \} \quad \text{for all } a \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, $$
though in part (b) we are restricting the domain to $[0,b)$. In the previous exercise, I proved the following facts which I believe might be useful for this exercise:

1. $a$ is increasing and right-continuous.
2. If $c(t) < \infty$ then $a(c(t)) \geq t$, with equality if and only if $c(t + \epsilon) > c(t)$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.

There is a theorem in Exercise 3.18 (p.19) of the text that states that if two $\sigma$-finite measures agree on a $p$-system which satisfies certain properties, then the measures are identical. Using this fact, I was able to reduce the problem to showing that $a^{-1}([0,t]) = [0,c(t)]$ for all $t \in [0,b)$. I was able to prove one inclusion, but I am stuck on the other.

> **My question:** How do we prove that $[0,c(t)] \subseteq a^{-1}([0,t])$ ?

Or equivalently,
$$ \text{Want to Show}: \quad x \leq c(t) \implies a(x) := \inf\{s \in [0,b): c(s) > x \} \leq t.$$

Here is my proof of the other inclusion: Let $x \in a^{-1}([0,t]) = \{u \in [0,b): 0 \leq a(u) \leq t \}$. Then $0 \leq a(x) \leq t$. Since $c$ is increasing, it follows that $0 \leq c(a(x)) \leq c(t)$. But $x \leq c(a(x))$ by simply reversing the roles of $c$ and $a$ in the argument from the previous exercise (which I'm omitting here). Thus, $0 \leq x \leq c(t)$, i.e. $x \in [0,c(t)]$.

I am quite stuck on the reverse inclusion. I've tried using the basic properties of the infimum and the fact that $a$ and $c$ are increasing and right-continuous, but I can't quite seem to make it work. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stuck on the reverse inclusion because it isn't true! A counterexample: Let $\mu$ place mass $1$ at $x=0$ and mass $1$ at $x=1$. You can check that
$$c(t)=\begin{cases} 1&\text{if $0\le t<1$}\\ 2 &\text{if $1\le t$}\end{cases}$$
and
$$
a(u)=\begin{cases} 0&\text{if $0\le u<1$}\\ 1&\text{if $1\le u<2$}\end{cases}
$$
However, your reverse inclusion asserts $$1\le c(0)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad a(1)\le 0,$$ which is not true.

The relation you *should* prove:
$$[0,c(t))\subset a^{-1}[0,t]\subset [0, c(t)],\tag{$\ast$}$$ is weaker than the one you were attempting yet still leads to the desired result $c(t)=\lambda (a^{-1}[0,t])$.

You've proved the second inclusion in $(\ast)$. The first inclusion is much easier to prove than the one you are stuck on -- it follows directly from the definition of inf.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a great answer! I was going crazy trying to figure this one out :)

Comment: Thankyou! After 20+ hours of also trying to prove things that are not true, that simple goal post enabled the solution. But I have one problem with it still...

Since it's possible that $\mu$ could have an atom at $t$, then really we must have $\mu[0, t) \leq \lambda \circ a^{-1}[0, 1] \leq \mu[0, t]$; unless I'm missing some other way of bringing something on the left of $\lambda \circ a^{-1}$ up to equality with $\mu$; in which case the hypothesis in the question is wrong? One should also insist that $\mu$ has no atoms?

Comment: @Mark  This argument should not be affected by the presence of atoms. Apply Lebesgue measure to (*) and you obtain $\lambda [0,c(t))\le \lambda(a^{-1}[0,t])\le \lambda[0,c(t)]$. Since the Lebesgue measure of an interval is its length, this implies $c(t)= \lambda\circ a^{-1} [0,t]$. But $c(t):=\mu[0,t]$ by definition of $c$,  hence $\mu[0,t]=\lambda\circ a^{-1}[0,t]$.