# "Time change" and measures from CDF and Lebesgue measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory

UDPATE

The following post contains enough information to answer this question

[Prove that $x \leq c(t) \implies \inf\{s \in [0,b): c(s) > x \} \leq t$ where $c$ is right-continuous and increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544005/prove-that-x-leq-ct-implies-inf-s-in-0-b-cs-x-leq-t-where-c?rq=1)

---

I'm working through Erhan Cinlar's book Probability and Stochastics. There is an exercise / complementary that seems fundamental, but I can't quite grab it; something he calls "time change" but uses to prove a result about standard measures. This is about that proof. Chapter 1 (Measure Theory) exercise 5.14.

Letting $\mu: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+) \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}_+}$ be a measure such that the CDF $c(t) := \mu[0,t] : \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}_+}$ is everywhere finite. It follows that $c$ is increasing and right continuous, so it follows from previous question that there is an $a : \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}_+}$ increasing and right continuous such that

$ a(u) = \inf \{ t \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ c(t) > u \}$

$ c(t) = \inf \{ u \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ a(u) > t \}$

Let $b = \lim c(t)$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0, b)$. I am to show that $\mu = \lambda \circ a^{-1}$

---

So I need to build the preimage function $a^{-1}: \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}_+}) \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+)$

Beginning with descibing the fibers

$a^{-1} \{t\} = \{u \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ t = a(u) \}$

$= \{u \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ t = \inf \{ t' \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ c(t') > u \} \}$

$a^{-1}[0, t] = \{u \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ [0, t] \ni \inf \{ t' \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ c(t') > u \} \}$

$= \{u \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ t \geq \inf \{ t' \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ c(t') > u \} \}$

From here every road I take is a dead end. Where do we go from here?

---

Update to address one suggestion in a comment below. Using the fact that $a$ is increasing, we can do this

$c(a(u)) = \inf \{u' \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ a(u') > a(u)\}$

$= u + \inf \{\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_+ ~|~ a(u + \epsilon) > a(u)\}$

In which case we see that $c(a(u)) \geq u$ with equality iff $\forall \epsilon > 0$ we have $a(u + \epsilon) > a(u)$

So while Cinlar calls them "functional inverses", they are not really. Each is a section of the other while it's moving.

Comment: It seems that Cinlar assumes that $c$ and $a$ are both strictly increasing so that
they are inverse to each other. It is quite easy to show instead of $\mu=\lambda\circ a^{-1}$ the equivalent statement that $\mu\circ c=\lambda\,.$

Comment: To be precise. All we need to realize is $$
\mu[0,t]=c(t)\,,\quad \lambda[0,t]=t=c(a(t))\,,\quad\lambda(a^{-1}[0,t])=c(a(a^{-1}(t)))=c(t)=\mu[0,t]\,.
$$

Comment: Well, they are "kind of" inverse to each other. There is an earlier exercise where we show that actually $a(c(t)) \geq t$ and equal iff $\forall \epsilon > 0$ we have $c(t + \epsilon) > c(t)$ (and symmetrically can show that $c(a(u)) \geq u$ with equality iff $\forall \epsilon > 0$ we have $a(u + \epsilon) > a(u)$.

So the part where we write $t = c(a(t))$ doesn't work unfortunately.